# com.rsa.jsse.JsseProvider not recognized

Tags: java, cryptography

I have to add above provider. I added in the java.security file.                 but I am not able to resolve the error.
what jar has above file.

Answer (score 0):

`sslj.jar` should have that file. It's part of the [BSAFE SSL-J](https://community.rsa.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/40092-102-1-10647/SSL-J_5.1.3_InstallGuide.pdf) product of RSA.

Comment: That is, the venerable company that put a NSA backdoor deliberately in their BSAFE product, in case you did miss that communication.

Comment: I tried but could not. There should be a jar. that must have above class definition right. can you tell me from where can i download that. thanks.